# Heroku - NodeJS Cant convert date to UTC

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, momentjs, utc

I need to create a date in my local time and convert it to UTC to be saved in a database.

I have the following code in my local environment and on Heorku:

```
// node dateTest.js

var moment = require('moment-timezone');
var timeZone = 'Pacific/Auckland';

var date = moment('20160101235959', 'YYYYMMDDHHmmss').tz(timeZone);

var UTCdate = date.utc().toISOString();

console.log(UTCdate);
```

When I run it locally I get:

`2016-01-01T10:59:59.000Z`

Which is the correct UTC time. But when I run it on Heorku instance I get:

`2016-01-01T23:59:59.000Z`

Which is the literal date with a Z on the end.

Why does this happen? I can't figure it out.  :(

NodeJS v5.1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked at the docs for `moment-timezone` and you can use it two different ways.  Instead of `utc()` you can use the second way.  I would change your code as follows:

```
var moment = require('moment-timezone');
var timeZone = 'Pacific/Auckland';

var date = moment.tz('20160101235959', 'YYYYMMDDHHmmss', timeZone);

var UTCdate = date.tz('Greenwich').toISOString();
console.log(UTCdate);
```

Comment: Just like that! :D Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Since your app could be running anywhere in the world, the default time zone for Heroku apps is UTC (so that it is consistent across dynos that could be in different time zones). You can run the following command to [set a time zone](http://blog.pardner.com/2012/08/setting-the-default-time-zone-for-a-heroku-app/):

```
heroku config:add TZ="America/Los_Angeles"
```

Comment: I don't want to use my local zone on Heorku, I want to use UTC.